# How to validate entry widgets in python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on a basic calculator program. I am trying to use the validate function so the user is only able to enter in values from the `valild_input` list. The `test_input` function which contains this list works fine until I decide to type in "=" or press the `equals button`. When I press the `equals_button` the current equation on the `display` entry isn't deleted and replaced with the result. Although this doesn't occur when I press the "=" key on the keyboard. The only issue is that the equals sign stays on the `display` and after that, the entry widget stops validating the user's input altogether.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def replace_text(text):
    display.delete(0, END)
    display.insert(0, text)

#Calculates the input in the display        
def calculate(event = None):
    equation = display.get()
    try:
        result = eval(equation)
        replace_text(result)
    except: 
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Math Error", parent = root)

def test_input(value, action):
    valid_input = ["7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "*", "0", ".", "/"]
    if action == "1":
        if value not in valid_input:
            return False
        return True

root = Tk() 
root.title("Calculator testing")

display = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 16), justify = "right", validate = "key")
display.configure(validatecommand = (display.register(test_input), "%S", "%d"))
display.insert(0, "")
display.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = "NSWE", padx = 10, pady = 10)
display.bind("=", calculate)

#Equals button
button_equal = Button(root, font = ("Helvetica", 14), text = "=", command = 
calculate, bg = "#c0ded9")
button_equal.grid(column = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = "WE")

#All clear button 
button_clear = Button(root, font = ("Helvetica", 14), text = "AC", command = lambda: replace_text(""), bg = "#c0ded9")
button_clear.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = "WE")

#Main Program       
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I'm not sure whether this question deserves to be closed as a duplicate. Yes it's about validation, but the question is not about how to get validation working, because it is working when you start running the program. However, sometimes validation "breaks", which is not explained by the question you linked (ok it's there somewhere, but the OP will probably never find it without more guidance).

Comment: ok, I see your point @fhdrsdg

Comment: From @ReblochonMasque's proposed duplicate: *"it's important that the validation command returns either True or False. Anything else will cause the validation to be turned off for the widget."* The `test_input` doesn't do that - there's a branch where it returns nothing, i.e. `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. **The validation function should always return a boolean.**

   From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/1222951):

   > It's important that the validation command returns either True or False. Anything else will cause the validation to be turned off for the widget.

   Your `test_input` function doesn't do that - there's a branch in which it returns `None`.

   ```
   def test_input(value, action):
       valid_input = ["7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "*", "0", ".", "/"]
       if action == "1":
           if value not in valid_input:
               return False
           return True
       # None is being returned here!
   ```

   This is why the validation is disabled after your program deletes text from the Entry. The fix is simple: return `True` instead of `None`.

   ```
   def test_input(value, action):
       valid_input = ["7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "*", "0", ".", "/"]
       if action == "1":
           if value not in valid_input:
               return False
           return True

       # if action != 1, allow it
       return True
   ```
2. **The validation function needs to handle multi-character input.**

   You've assumed that the validation function is called for every single character that's entered. This is true when the user types a formula with their keyboard, but not when copy/pasting or setting the entry's text with `.insert(...)`. Your function needs to handle these cases.

   ```
   def test_input(value, action):
       valid_input = ["7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "*", "0", ".", "/"]
       if action == "1":
           return all(char in valid_input for char in value)

       # if action != 1, allow it
       return True
   ```

Comment: I did try your solution, but the result is not being displayed when I press equals button the validations thinks the replaced text isn't a valid input.

Comment: The validation only works for one digit results so like results from 0-9 and stops working for a result of 10 and onwards.